# android studio new project missing folders

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a new project using the latest version of Android Studio (0.2.2), this is a fresh install of studio. When I am in the project explorer view, it fails to show me any folders for my project. I should see a root project folder, and within it the .idea, gradle, and module folders, but they are not showing.

Here is what I expect to see (taken from the sample project created on first boot):

[image]

But here is what I see immediately after the project's creation:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to expose my project's folders! I do not want to develop without the project explorer, it's simply too much of a hassle. Did I create the project incorrectly, or am I missing some not-so-obvious setting somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Open your android studio while internet connection is there, it will download some files...let it download those files itself. Once those files are downloaded, you can use android studio offline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio "Project Structure" not coming properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727505/android-studio-project-structure-not-coming-properly)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is that I assumed android studio would create a module for the application. I assumed this because it asked me at the beginning for app name, module name, package, sdk info etc.

This assumption turned out to be false. **You must create your first module manually through File > Project Structure.** After that is done, the project explorer shows the files.

Comment: Then why does the src file exist in the subfolder with the project name when creating the project?

Comment: I assume because this is a bug. When I create a new project on another PC of mine, the first module is already created for me in Studio, I don't need to add it manually.

Comment: Like Niek said, I am curious why a module isn't being created automatically.  I have tried on both my home and work computers.  The files are definitely there on the file system.

Comment: I fixed the issue without manually creating a module.  See my answer.

Answer (score 14):

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules
2. Add Button (Green plus button) click -> New Module Select
3. New Module window -> "Content root" change path button click to select "Project root file path"
4. Apply to change save and "OK" button exit.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set this as the default so I don't have to do this every time I make a new project?

Comment: This solution works like a charm! Another stupid android bug, i guess.

Answer (score 7):

In the project Explorer there is a drop down menu where you have selected project, now change it to project files.

I hope this will solve your problem. reply if it didn't.

Comment: Project explorer says "Nothing to show" when I have project files selected

Comment: tell me one thing, you created new project or imported existing project. because if you have imported the existing project then probably your project isn't imported correctly. and if you are importing existing project which was created in eclipse then you have to follow instructions as given on this link - [link] http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new gradle project not a new android project.
Update your android studio tools to 0.2.3 - Go to Help menu - select check for update.
then Update your android sdk tools, android support repository, android support library and android build tools using android sdk manager.

[image]
And update some configuration in project structure. Go to File menu->project structure -> in projects tab select Android SDK as default sdk and in SDKs tab set correct path to updated android sdk.

Now restart android studio and try to create a new project and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

(Noted for posterity) I had a similar issue come up recently, when importing an Eclipse android project. The issue was that the source folder wasn't added as such. I had to manually go into Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources and make sure that the "src" folder wasn't excluded and was marked a source folder.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is asked years ago. But now following simple solution worked for me.

Clicking 'Sync Project With Gradle files' makes all directories visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, there are some problem if you upgrade from 0.1.9 version to 0.2.0 in Windows.

[Android Studio 0.2.0 Release](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio020released)

The solution (which worked for me) was to completely uninstall Android Studio and reinstall the 0.2.0 version.

Comment: I installed 0.2.2 fresh, and didn't have a previous installation on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Additionally, the IDE posted an "Assertion Error" into its event log.

Downloading and reinstalling the preview version, then applying the patch to 0.2.6 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SDK to a level that you have installed in the SDK manager. The SDK manager can be accessed from `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`. For me, Android Studio was packaged with `API Level 17` but the new project wizard tried to target `API Level 18`.