# Subfolders not being imported from Git using Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I'm trying to import my project that's hosted on BitBucket using Android Studio. I'm using the VCS -> Checkout from Version Control System -> Git menu option and connecting to my BitBucket account. All files in the root directory of the repo are being imported flawlessly. However, none of the main subfolders (there are about 6-7 folders) are being imported into Android Studio. I've tried everything that I came across via a Google Search but I'm lost as to how to do this now.

I'm assuming I may not have configured my gradle scripts correctly, maybe? I can import the project just fine from my local computer's copy (the file/folder structure is exactly the same on the local computer and my Git repo). Another interesting thing is that the folders are being downloaded to my specified project folder from Git. They just aren't showing up in Android Studio. Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From : [android studio new project missing folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961397/android-studio-new-project-missing-folders)

The problem here is that I assumed android studio would create a module for the application. I assumed this because it asked me at the beginning for app name, module name, package, sdk info etc.

This assumption turned out to be false. You must create your first module manually through File > Project Structure. After that is done, the project explorer shows the files.

Comment: Perfect! Worked flawlessly.