# Android Studio 0.8.1: imported project, missing root folder

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I imported my Eclipse project to Android Studio. Import succeeded except that root project folder in not shown in the Project tab; only nested modules are visible.

[image: No project root folder]

How do I make project's root folder appear on top of modules?

P.S. I looked into [android studio new project missing folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961397/android-studio-new-project-missing-folders) but the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: May sound stupid but have you tried shutting it down and reopening it again? Whats your underlying directory structure like? Are each of these modules located underneath your overall project directory?

Comment: Sadly reopening doesn't help. Yes, there is a project root directory, and all of these modules are right underneath this directory.

Comment: The modules are appearing as thought they are referenced as a dependency rather than physically being under the project root. I'm sorry, I'm stumped

Comment: I'm stumped too :) Thanks for help anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the import wizard didn't create an `.iml` file for the root project module.

I have solved this by closing the project then importing it again by double clicking on the project's folder (not on `build.gradle`). So it created this `.iml` file and now is displaying the root folder in its place.

P.S. I did reimport with Android Studio 0.8.3, maybe they have fixed something.