# How to Import project into Android Studio and show project folder, not app module

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am trying to import a gradle project that has one 'app' module into Android Studio 0.8.4. During the import, I select the project folder above 'app'. After the import, however, the iml file is only created under the app directory (app/app.iml) and therefore the top level folders in the project are not visible. Android studio opens up into (.../myproject/app)

How can I import my existing gradle project into Android Studio and have it open into (../myproject/)?

I also tried with 0.8.2 and had the same issue.

PS: I saw this similar question, but no matter how many times I try it is still not working for me:
[Android Studio 0.8.1: imported project, missing root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703734/android-studio-0-8-1-imported-project-missing-root-folder)

(There were times when importing the same project twice would do the trick for some reason, but that workaround has stopped working for me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I closed the project completely, then I imported it again as non android studio project