# Importing Android Studio project from BitBucket only imports gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to get an Android Studio project from BitBucket to work on another computer.

When I cloned the project and tried "import an existing Android Studio project", I had the option to select my gradle location or use customizable gradle wrapper.

I tried giving gradle the location to the gradle plugin, but that gave me an error.
Then I tried the gradle wrapper option, but now the Android Studio project is called "gradle",
it only contains the gradle directory.

The app folder is missing.

Am I using a wrong workflow or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here:
[android studio new project missing folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961397/android-studio-new-project-missing-folders)

This was my solution:
File -> Project Structure -> Modules
Add Button (Green plus button) click -> New Module Select
New Module window -> "Content root" change path button click to select "Project root file path"
Apply to change save and "OK" button exit.

Thank you user1628775!