# How do you view the project tree in Android Studio v0.2.x?

Tags: android, tree, project, gradle, android-studio

I can't seem to find the project files in to the newer version of Android Studio. In the screenshot below you can see that it doesn't display the entire project tree.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts172.png

The solution offered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727505/android-studio-project-structure-not-coming-properly) post doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: The same happened to me. This was actually the last straw that together with other bugs made me go back to Eclipse. Android Studio is just not ready for production yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me too, in [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) it says something about upgrading:

> Windows users: Do not install Android Studio 0.2.x in the same location as 0.1.x. Doing so may cause errors such as ClassCastException or other unexpected behaviors. It's best if you remove your previous version of Android Studio 0.1.x.

I fixed it uninstalling my currend Android Studio installation, removing the folder where it was installed with the remaining files, and installing it again. It works correctly now apparently.

Answer (score 5):

Press alt+1

this work on my android studio 0.3.5 on linux

Comment: If possible, add the documentation/link for the hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem on Android Studio 1.2.2. I have closed and reopen project.