# Android Studio not showing modules in project structure

Tags: android, module, android-studio, project-structure

I am using Android studio and I want to add module to my project like
"action bar Sherlock" or jar files,
but when I opened the project structure there is no module or library in the menu :\

[image]

In intelij it's appearing:

[image]

So what's the problem? How can I add these modules in Android studio?

Comment: I have the same issue and can't seem to figure it out. Have you figured it out yet? If yes, please share your answer.

Comment: Have the Same issues, so stupid...Is doesn't show anything. I need other setting like global setting or others...OMG

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems this problem only occurs with the imported project.

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27501885/2835520) help

Answer (score 65):

**Update 19 March 2019**

A new experience someone has just faced recently even though he/she did add a *library* module in *app* module, and include in Setting gradle as described below. One more thing worth trying is to make sure your *app* module and your *library* module have the same compileSdkVersion (which is in each its gradle)!

Please follow this link for more details.

*Ref:* [Imported module in Android Studio can't find imported class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477052/imported-module-in-android-studio-cant-find-imported-class/48679879#48679879)

**Original answer**

Sometimes you use import module function, then the module does appear in Project mode but not in Android mode

[image]

[image]
So the thing works for me is to go to Setting gradle, add my module manually, and sync a gradle again:

[image]

Comment: even if you already have it inside the settings.gradle file , delete it and add it again at a different place (the end of file for example so that android detect a change in the file ) then sync gradle

Answer (score 18):

First, create your `Module`. You can do that using the default Android Studio Module Wizard (`File -> New -> New Module`), select Android Library, give it a Name and a package name, and finish.
After that you will see that nothing happens. Open the side `Gradle Projects Section` ***(should be somewhere on the right panel)***

You should see something like this:

[image]

Expand your module gradle and run the `Run Configurations` task.
After that refresh the content and refresh the project structure.

It should work now.

Answer (score 12):

Do right mouse click on your project, then select 'Open Module Settings' - then you can add modules to your project..

Comment: I don't see how I can use this to add modules that are in the directory though? I only see ways to add new modules..

Comment: Thanks in android studio 2.3.3 I don't know what happened it was first in project structure

Answer (score 10):

Go to File->Project Structure-> Project Settings -> Modules.

Click on the green colored + and add new module. select Application module and set the content root to your project module.

Click next and then finish.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906979/609782)

Comment: This is very helpful post. I have one correction, that is : After selecting my project, it saying "app" already in project. In that case i added as "app1" and click ok. After that IDE shows both module "app" and "app1". Then i deleted "app1" from project structure and run project after selecting "app" module. Then it works very well.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, after switching to a branch that did not have my module, then switching back.

`Clean Project` -> `Rebuild Project` did **not** work for me.

But `File` -> `Invalidate caches/restart` **did** work.

Comment: Invalidate caches/restart save my day :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a `gradle.settings` file to your root project structure, after that when you "Open Module settings" you will the menu aligned to your `gradle.settings`. When importing a project to Android Studio, it doesn't create this file for you. Sometimes it's usually better to start a clean project and move your code there, it's usually easier to achieve.

Answer (score 7):

This Might be help some:

> To import module as library in your project.

1. File > New > Import Module
2. Select Valid path in Source Dir..
3. Tick on Import > Finish

> Now Open Module setting:

1. Go to File > Project Structure > Modules
2. Modules > Dependency > click on Green Plus Sign.
3. Click on Module Dependency > locate module > and Implement your module.

if your module is not shown in "Choose Modules Window"

Follow the below step..

1. Open Settings.Gradle file
2. include ':app', 'Put your module name here' and sync project.

Follow Open Module Setting as above.

Answer (score 7):

As for me issue was that the first line in the `build.gradle` file of the OpenCV library.

It was something like this:
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
This refers to the fact that the imported OpenCV is an application and not a library. It exists for OpenCV above 4.1.0. So change it to:
Something like this:
`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

You might get an error in ApplicationId, comment it out in the gradle file.

Answer (score 6):

Open settings.gradle and add the module as below,

```
include ':app',':bottomnav'
```

here i have added my newly imported module `':bottomnav'` separated with a comma. then Sync your project. your module will be visible to dependency.
Android Studio only displays those module, which are defined in the settings.gradle file of your application.
after defining the module in settings.gradle, you will be able to add the module as dependency of your application.

Comment: best answer in my opinion. Thanks @kiran

Answer (score 5):

Check **settings.gradle**. You'll find this : `include ':app'`

Just add your own module name and it should look like this :

```
include ':app', ':yourModuleName'
```

Sync.

That's it.

Comment: this worked but wondering why settings file is not already in the project by default

Comment: If your project is created successfully for the 1st time then obviously the settings.gradle will be there.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue when running version control on a project in Android Studio (0.4.2). When pulling it down to a new location and importing the modules, only the "Android SDK" were showing in the Project Structure.

I removed the .idea/ folder from the version control, by adding it to .gitignore file, and did a fresh pull and imported the modules. Now all the settings appeared correctly in the Project Settings and Platform Settings for the Project Structure.

Comment: Modules were added and pushed from a machine, then pulled from a 2nd machine, but here they were not visible as module. Deleting folder .idea made regenerating the workspace.xml

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did to solve this problem

- Close Android Studio
- Quick Start -> Check out from Version Control

Comment: I don't understand. Where is quick start and what version control?

Comment: Quick Start is the window that shows up when you launch Android Studio

Comment: What Lucas means was Click on File > Close project. And after that a window opens which is called Quick Start and do as Lucas says.

Answer (score 2):

Please go to Module settings
and choose Modules from Project Settings 
then you need to Select src and gen folders and marked them as Source folders by right-click on them and select Source

Answer (score 1):

First You Have To Add Name Of Your Module In setting.gradle(Project Setting) File Like This..

```
include ':app', ':simple-crop-image-lib'
```

Then You Need To Compile This Module Into build.gradle(Module app) File Like This..

```
implementation project(':simple-crop-image-lib')
```

That's all for adding module now it will be appear in android  section or project section as well.

If It's till did't appear rebuild or clean your project..

Answer (score 1):

Although not similar to the question above,

In my case,
The module is not visible in the android tab,
I saw it in the project tab.

After deleting the **.idea/workspace.xml** file, (I guess there is a problem because the unloadlist list remains here?)
When I reopened the project, it worked fine.

Additionally,
When **invalidate caches** (clear VCS Log caches and indexes),
It shows up for new modules, not for previously deleted modules (this only worked when deleting workspace.xml).

Comment: This problem seems to occur when you right-click a module in the ide and then unload module.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Not only was it not visible in the Android structure, it was visible in the Project structure, however it was erroring out in my code space. Everything was building correctly and module was properly set in all areas, but the imports in the file heads were failing to find the module. The above solution is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the modules, modify your workspace.xml file and settings.gradle file to use the new paths of your module.
Otherwise you will need to try using the import module feature.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory name is lower case.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, check that all the modules are listed in your `settings.gradle` file.

- If they are not, add them.
- If they are, change something/anything in the file so that the **Sync Project** prompt comes on. Sync and your project should compile fine; the modules you're looking for will appear in your project structure.

Answer (score -1):

in my case somehow build.gradle file deleted under app i restore it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).