# Android Studio - Unable to import class after added dependency in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies

I am unable to import class after added dependency in build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Sync it with no error. Did some search about this issue. I found that it may be related to Project Structure -> Project -> Plugin Version. [Imported module in Android Studio can't find imported class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477052/imported-module-in-android-studio-cant-find-imported-class) But I am not sure what version I should use.

My project version

```
Gradle version: 4.1
Android Plugin Version 3.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mcxiaoke library is  [depricated now](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

```
      com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

[try official by google](https://github.com/google/volley)

try replacing your compile with this

```
 compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```