# Android Studio dependencies of module not visible in other module

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a module called "Common" as library, this module has few dependencies like: `com.badlogicgames.gdx`, `com.squareup.wire` etc. And it works fine, I use them inside of this module.

And I have another module called "Tracking", where in the gradle I have:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':Common')
}
```

And if I try there to import any public class of module "Common", it works fine, but if I try to import any class of library `com.badlogicgames.gdx`or `com.squareup.wire`, it says me "Cannot resolve symbol ..." and hightlight it red. And no code autocompleting for such classes.

However the project compiles and starts on the device without errors.

Has somebody any idea? I tried "clean and rebuild" for project, "invalidate cashes and restart" for Android Studio. Nothing helps.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067846/android-studio-not-showing-modules-in-project-structure/31509751

Comment: @basavarajganagi my Project Structure is ok, there are all modules and their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

in the module `common` you need to declare those transitive dependencies as `api` to expose them to other modules:

e.g. common/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.squareup.wire'
}
```

https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2017/06/14/androidstudio3/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Change compile to api

```
dependencies {
  api project(':Common')
}
```

**Reason**

Because **compile** is deprecated, so it is been treated as **implementation**. 
FYI **compile** and **api** (new keyword for compile) are same in which all internal modules are visible.
But new gradle project having **compile** keyword are treated as **implementation**. and in **implementation** internal modules are not visible to main project.

**Suggestion**

You should declare dependency in your gradle because it is not good to make leak of internal modules.

Comment: I use old gradle version `distributionUrl=../../../../androidGradleDistribution/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: What is keyword other module using for declaring `squareup.wire`?

Comment: `compile 'com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:2.1.0'`

Comment: You must declare this dependency to your project too, perhaps this is AAR, which does not contain nested dependencies.

Comment: It means I will have the same library twice in the project and the size of project increases. Strange is the thing, that it worked in the past, but last few days I get this problem.

Comment: That will not be twice in your project if you use same version.

Comment: It's surely not a library issue, because I can run app and it works with theese "unvisible" classes well without exceptions. It means the library is there and can be used.