# Android studio run my application no module found issue?

Tags: android

[image: No module error]

when running the application, in the drop down list of module I have found a "no module found" error. How to setup the module?

Comment: is your build successful ?

Comment: Reference link is below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067846/android-studio-not-showing-modules-in-project-structure