# android- project structure is not opening

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm using android studio v1.4 . I want to use a library from modules ,I need to go to project structure but when ever I choose project structure from file menu , it doesn't open anything .

I've restarted my computer , I invalidated cashes and restarted , I've tried other peojects but it doesnot work at all .

What should I do ? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: try `file` -> `new module` then check your logcat if it returns any error

Comment: @Scar thanks for reply , it opens and returns no error

Comment: entering project structure does not return any result for you? Have you checked the target project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio "Project Structure" not coming properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727505/android-studio-project-structure-not-coming-properly)

Comment: @Scar no it does not return any thing , What is target project ?

Comment: @AshishJaiswal I've seen this post before, the problem is project structure window is not opening at all

Comment: So if you chose `Android` structure, it shows the content properly? But whenever you choose `Project` structure, it shows blank field? Or you cannot see the folders but the gradle is present?

Comment: **Better backup everything first before doing this:** 
1. Close android studio first
2. delete file `ProjectRoot\build\intermediates\model_data.bin`
3. Re-open Android studio
4. Re-build just to be sure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889250/android-studio-project-structure-not-displaying-properly