# Android Studio Project Structure not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-virtual-device

My `Android Studio 1.3.2` was working properly,but it restart it self and then i am not able to see `Android` type to select project structure and also i am not able to find `SDK` Manger,`AVD` Manager icons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution for that,

First of all, I tried with `Invalidate Caches and Restart` then my android studio restarted and then I clicked on `Edit Configuration`. I selected `Android Application Project` and my project got scanned and it is working now.