# Android Studio not detecting my module

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I cloned my repo and now Android studio (1.3.1) is having hard time detecting my module 'app'

It is not showing any module in edit configuration(as in image below).

[image]

It's already defined in 'Settings.gradle'

```
include ':app'
```

I tried importing this app module but it says `project already contains module with this name`

Tried other solutions too. Stuck here.

Note: This repo doesn't have .iml file of project.

Comment: Have you tried solution from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727505/android-studio-project-structure-not-coming-properly/18906979#18906979) answer?

Comment: @lidkxx I went File > Project Structure > Project, But there is no modules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Different SDK installation worked for me.
```

How I came to know?:
(Meanwhile 2 days passed in this issue, I tried all possible solutions like adding facets, adding modules etc. (I came to know it is working in other collegue's machine ) But they didn't work, So last option for me was fresh installation of Android Studio. So I...)

1. Installed Android Studio 2.2.3 with different sdk location unknowingly(Let's say **loc2**).

2. It was working, later I made batch update to 2.3.2. After update, I chose project location as sdk location (Lets say **loc1** ). This time it din't work and I got same error. This was a moment when switching to **loc2** worked!!

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue with Android Studio 3.5.3.

Deleting .iml and local.properties files along with .idea and .gradle folders before reopening the project fixed my issue.

Comment: Deleting .idea and "Invalidate and Restart" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had renamed my module directory from `oldmodule` to `app`, but the project's `settings.gradle` still had

```
include ':oldmodule'
```

Changing that to

```
include ':app'
```

and re-syncing gradle made it appear again as module.