# Android Studio settings changed after cloning project from Github

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

For the first time I cloned this project from github and after that all setting of my android studio are changed. AVD Manger is Missing , Android from Project is missing , Build APK is missing and many other things It is completely changed. I am unable to fix this.  Please help me and explain how to fix this . What has happened to android studio?
This is the project link: https://github.com/HoraApps/LeafPic
I have added screenshot, please have a look:
[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

[Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi2Ni.png)

[image: Fourth Image]

[image: Fifth Image]

If possible fix this using TeamViewer.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550994

Comment: I have already checked out, but that is not working for me

Comment: What about the accepted answer at the same question? The problem is definitely that your project is not recognized as an Android one.

Comment: But the problem exists with all my project  which were recognized by android studio before but now no any project are recognized by android studio

Answer (score 0):

Exit Android Studio and restart or open this project with Android studio or Gradle icon on it project parent directory.This means directory is Android project.You must have opened wrong directory thus no option are show.

Comment: This is not for any single project , Every project are opening with same missing settings.